# Newly Published App reporting Version as "Unknown" in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

New version of my app is 1.2. But in "Sales and Trends" in iTunes Connect I see "unknown" app version. Also new reviews not showing in App Store in "Current version" tab (only in all versions tab).
What's wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find why?

Comment: Same issue, old version shows up normally, newly release version appears as unknown.

Comment: Sent request in ITC Support. No answer yet.

Comment: @DmitryPrivalov did you get an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I updated the latest version. I cleared out my browser history and cache and it is now working. If that doesn't work for you, try another browser. I usually use Chrome. Before clearing out Chrome's cache/history, I decided to try Safari. No luck. Then I tried Firefox and it worked there.

I've also noticed it can take several days for thing to update consistently across all the various pages.   Like sales may not show anything for a recent week, but if I wait long enough and update/clear/etc, sales data shows.

Comment: i'm assuming you mean updating App Store connect to the latest version